# Controlling Order of React Component Rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As you know React components render in parallel.  There is no guarantee in order that they finish rendering.

I want to render the following components in this exact order:

1. **InterviewContentMain** (because it will render the header

   .  I need this header to render first so that I can act on it in my other two components after rendered.  I am going to run some JS on it, etc. later on from those other two component's componentDidMount so that's why I want this to render first)
2. **InterviewContainer** (should only render after InterviewContentMain has rendered)
3. **TableOfContents** (should only render after InterviewContainer and InterviewContentMain have rendered)

Here is a little more context https://youtu.be/OrEq5X9O4bw

I tried a bunch of stuff as you can see with the lifecycle methods, which is probably totally wrong or not even sure it's what people are even doing for this sort of scenario, but no luck so far.

```
const Main = Component({
    getInitialState() {
        console.log("getInitialState being called");
        return null;
    },
    renderMe() {
        console.log("changed InterviewContent's state");
        this.setState({renderInk: true});
    },
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("InterviewContentMain mounted");
    },
    render(){
        var company = this.props.company;

        return (
            <div id="ft-interview-content">
                <p className="section-heading bold font-22" id="interview-heading">Interview</p>
                <InterviewContent renderMe={this.renderMe} company={company}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
})

export default InterviewContentMain;


const InterviewContent = Component({
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("InterviewContent mounted");
    },
    renderMe() {
        console.log("changed InterviewContent's state");
        this.setState({subParentRendered: true});
    },
    render(){
        var company = this.props.company;

        return (
            <div id="interview-content" className="clear-both">
                <div className="column-group">
                    <div className="all-20">
                        <TableOfContents renderHeader={this.props.renderMe}  renderContent={this.renderMe} company={company}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="all-80">
                        <InterviewContainer company={company}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
})

const TableOfContents = Component({
    enableInk() {
        new Ink.UI.Sticky(el, {topElement: "#interview-heading", bottomElement: "#footer"});
    },
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("table of contents mounted");
        this.renderHeader;
        this.renderContent;
        enableInk(); // I only want to run this if the Header and the Content have rendered first
    },
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <p className="margin-8"><span className="blue medium"><Link to="/">HOME</Link></span></p>
        )
    }
})
```

UPDATE:

here's what I tried.  While they all 3 render, I'm still getting times where TableOfContents renders before InterviewContentMain or InterviewContent which means TableOfContent after rendered overlaps `<p className="section-heading bold font-22" id="interview-heading">Interview</p>` instead of rendering underneath it due to the sticky JS I tried to apply in TableOfContents

```
const InterviewContentMain = Component({
    getInitialState() {
        console.log("getInitialState being called");
        return {rendered: false};
    },
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("InterviewContentMain mounted")
        this.setState({rendered: true});
    },
    render(){
        var company = this.props.company;

        return (
            <div id="ft-interview-content">
                <div className="section-heading bold font-22" id="interview-heading">Interview</div>
                { this.state.rendered && <InterviewContent company={company}/> }
            </div>
        )
    }
})

export default InterviewContentMain;


const InterviewContent = Component({
    getInitialState() {
        console.log("getInitialState being called");
        return {rendered: false};
    },
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("InterviewContent mounted")
        this.setState({rendered: true});
    },
    render(){
        var company = this.props.company;

        return (
            <div id="interview-content" className="clear-both">
                <div className="column-group">
                    <div className="all-20">
                        <TableOfContents company={company}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="all-80">
                        <InterviewContainer company={company}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
})

const TableOfContents = Component({
    componentDidMount() {
        const el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
        new Ink.UI.Sticky(el,{topElement: "#interview-heading", bottomElement: "#footer"});
        console.log("TableOfContents mounted");
    },
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <p className="margin-8"><span className="blue medium"><Link to="/">HOME</Link></span></p>
            </div>
        )
    }
})
```

Comment: Of course you can control the order of rendering. `{ someProp && <Component /> }`

Comment: It's like an `if` statement... only render `Component` if `someProp` is true

Comment: what @azium means is that you can render a component conditionally, thus you can control when a component is rendered (after `someProp` casts to `true`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to conditionally render a component, wrap it in a conditional (whether a function or an inline boolean expression)

You say:

> TableOfContents (should only render after InterviewContainer and InterviewContentMain have rendered)

.. so inside the `render` method of `TableOfContents` parent container, check whether some values are true, like you would in an `if` statement.

```
render(){
    var company = this.props.company;

    return (
        <div id="interview-content" className="clear-both">
            <div className="column-group">
                <div className="all-20">
                  {this.state.subParentRendered &&
                    <TableOfContents renderHeader={this.props.renderMe}  renderContent={this.renderMe} company={company}/>
                  }
                </div>
                <div className="all-80">
                    <InterviewContainer company={company}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: So... I've read your question and comments more carefully and I think the issue here boils down to: "How can I send props up to a parent". And the answer is... pass a callback function to a child, who calls it, for instance in `componentDidMount`. which specifically says: Hey parent! I rendered!

Comment: wouldn't  {this.state.rendered && be evaluated before it even gets set!?

Comment: no I don't want to send props to a parent.  I want parent to notify children when it's done so children render after it.  Check out my updated code..my 2nd attempt

Comment: here is the problem visually.  The TableOfContents should ALWAYS render after the header <p> because I am applying a JS sticky to it and telling it to always render below the interview-header section.  Well this vid shows that sometimes it's still rendering prior thus overlapping the Interview header https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9dIRR32HkH8

Comment: Thanks for that last vid I see what you're saying now. Thinking... my hunch is this is something weird about `Ink.UI.Sticky` not the "order of rendering" which seems pretty predictable to me by default

Comment: I still feel like if your initial question is "how do I render a Parent before a Child" then my answer should suffice because the child will never render until some condition is met, which is up to you to set.

Comment: that's what I thought I did in my last example but it's not working.  I have a condition in InterviewContentMain which is to check the state to see if Main was rendered yet.  This still doesn't work.  TableOfContents is still being rendered before the parent at times still somehow

Comment: You asked if `this.state.rendered` will be evaluated before it gets set... the answer to that is: at first it will be undefined or false, then the parent mounts and you set it to be true (or some other state variable) and once its true because the parent mounts, the child will render

Comment: right but it's clearly not happening because in the vid, it's jumping around because at times TableOfContents is not finding interview-header

Comment: try wrapping it in a timeout to *make sure* `setTimeout(() => this.setState(..), 1000)`

Comment: Also... keep in mind that when React calls `render` that doesn't mean "draw on the DOM", that means run the reconciliation algo which will find out what to draw, if anything, in the DOM that has changed since the last state change. So if you don't render a child right away (component not mounted yet), then React will put the dom nodes up, then you set state, then the child renders and calls componentDidMount. Since your UI is not reflecting this flow I presume it is not a React related problem. (no possibility of concurrent renders)

Comment: trying to wrap my head around what you just said.  "So if you don't render a child right away (component not mounted yet), then React will put the dom nodes up, then you set state, then the child renders and calls componentDidMount" - not sure what you are saying, can you rephrase that somehow

Comment: I'm just talking about the lifecycle of a what actually changes on the DOM. First the parent will call render, and recursively call render on a child components. Since `rendered` is false, no child `render` functions get called. Then React paints the dom and calls `componentDidMount`. At this point, the dom node is guaranteed to be in the DOM... React repeats step 1 but this time `rendered` is true and calls your child component. If your child component does something strange it's no longer React's fault

Comment: If `componentDidMount` violated that basic guarantee then it would be a totally useless function

Comment: just wondering when it "repeats"..when I refresh the page?   Oh it repeats when set the rendered state to true.  I'm assuming in chrome tools console you read the stack trace from bottom-up to get sequence of events

Comment: Or if it unmounts and mounts again like, for instance, if you toggle `this.state.rendered` and have `{this.state.rendered && <Child />}`.. Child component will call `componentDidMount` everytime `rendered` is set to `true`

Comment: right if you change the state of a parent, it re-renders all children...ok

Comment: well yes, but that doesn't mean `componentDidMount` will get called again... like sometimes it mounts once, the parent state changes, but the child hasn't unmounted for any reason so only `componentWillReceiveProps` and `shouldComponentUpdate` get called. `render` will always get called unless `shouldComponentUpdate` is `false`

Comment: yea my code seems to be working as far as the sequence I'm trying to call them in now with my second attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `setState` in `componentDidMount`. Call it in `componentWillMount`. It is an anti-pattern to call `setState` in `componentDidMount` immediately because `componentDidMount` is the one that calls `render`, see [this discussion](https://hashnode.com/post/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-call-setstate-immediately-after-componentdidmount-in-react-cim5vz8kn01flek53aqa22mby).

I have used slightly different syntax but it should be clearly understandable.

```
class InterviewContentMain ...
    this.state = {
      firstRendered: false
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      this.setState({ firstRendered: true });
    }

    render() {
      return (
      {this.state.firstRendered && 
       <InterviewContent />
      }
      );
    }

class InterviewContent ...
    this.state = {
      second: false
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      this.setState({ secondRendered: true });
    }

    render() {
      return (
      {this.state.secondRendered && 
       <TableOfContents />
      }
      );
    }

class TableOfContents ...

    render() {
      return (
       <div>Hello World in order</div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: ok but you're not passing secondRendered as a prop to TableOfContents.  How does TableOfContents know what this.state.secondRendered is?  Don't you want to pass it as a prop from InterviewContent?

Comment: also wouldn't {this.state.secondRendered && <TableOfContents />); itself be enough?  TableOfContents simply won't render after secondRendered, not sure why I'd need any check in my TableOfContents

Comment: My code is working, it seems to be rendering in the order I want....so I think I'm good.  Thanks

Comment: You don't need to pass it as a prop. Take a look at:

          {this.state.secondRendered && 
           <TableOfContents />
          }

This blocks the next render before previous render is complete.
Please accept the answer it it worked for you :)

Comment: then how does it know what that is?  this stands for TableOfContents.  State is internal to the component via `this`.

Comment: `this` corresponds to the class where `this` is used. TableOfContents does not need to know where it is being called from and when. InterviewContent controls when it wants to call it.

Comment: "{this.state.secondRendered && 
       <TableOfContents />
      );".  Sorry what do you mean by previous render.  Wouldn't it only render if InterviewContent rendered first always?

Comment: React re-renders the effected elements whenever there is a state change. When you changed state `secondR‌​endered` in `componentDidMount` of InterviewContent, you ask react to run the render function again and this time `this.state.secondR‌​endered` is set to true, so `{this.state.secondR‌​endered && <TableOfContents /> )}` results in rendering of TableOfContents this time.

Comment: what I'm saying is you have  {this.state.secondRendered &&  ---inside the TableOfContents--- component too.  `this` in that case means the internal state of TableOfContents.  Nowhere are you setting any kind of secondRendered property for state in TableOfContents.   You're only doing that within the scope of InterviewContent so the way you have it, TableOfContents will have no clue what secondRendered because it doesn't exist inside TableOfContents

Comment: You need to brush up react some more it seems. `this.state.secondRe‌​ndered` is a property of InterviewContent. Why would TableOfContents be bothered with it? We are using InterviewContent to block render of TableOfContents before `this.state.secondRe‌​ndered` is set to true. Note that `this` here corresponds to the `InterviewContent` class.

Comment: Which was exactly what I just said and was explaining you don't need that there

Comment: You probably didn't mean to also have it in TableOfContents

Comment: Wow I am so sorry. I didn't realize that before you put that in capital letters :'( I'll make the edit. I was arguing with reference to what I thought I had written. Thanks and sorry for the trouble.